# Тебе есть, чем заняться

Tags: пунктуация

Тебе есть, чем заняться. Я вот провожу время впустую.

Стоит ли запятая после "есть" и, если да, на каком основании?

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:
 Внутри выражений типа ***есть чем заняться***, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить, состоящих из глагола *быть*, или *найти* (*найтись*), или *остаться* и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (*кто, что, где, куда, когда* и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, **запятая не ставится**:
*Тебе есть в мире что забыть.

Бранить есть кому, кормить — некому.

Есть чему и нравиться.

И нашу интеллигенцию есть за что любить, есть за что уважать.

Есть над чем задуматься.

Нашли чем удивить.

Не нашёлся что сказать.

У нас будет чем козырнуть.

Нашла где модничать.

Есть когда с тобой болтать!

Было отчего приуныть.

Друзьям есть о чём поговорить.

Ребятам было где проводить свободное время.

Нам было в чём упрекнуть его.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146

Comment: А каким членом предложения является сочетание "чем заняться"?

Comment: Входит в сказуемое. На то оно называется цельным.